# Woocommerce: Skip cart and go to checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So, I can make an order programmatically, but then when I try to use mysite.com/checkout, it redirects me to mysite.com/cart which has no items... I have tried to redirect hook:

```
function skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout() {

    // If is cart page, redirect checkout.
    if( is_cart() )
        wp_redirect( WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() );
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout');
```

But then I get an error saying there is too many redirects...

So, apparently, this is not possible...

However, you can create orders programmatically, so how do I get my customers to be able to pay for their orders? Is there a shortcut to adding to cart at the same time that I `wc_create_order()`?

Comment: Check this reference:
https://wpbeaches.com/skip-cart-go-straight-to-checkout-page-in-woocommerce/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I still end up at the cart page with a "cannot checkout if cart is empty message"

Comment: This is a real development, as woocommerce don't handle checkout for empty cart (and empty checkout form). All the process is based on the cart object and on the checkout form and options. Is not possible to redirect customer to checkout if cart is empty… This subject is **too broad for StackOverFlow** and this question is a duplicate from your other question, which is not really allowed… So please [read the rules in HELP center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Oh, you WANT to go to an empty cart. What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: Nah, the orders are created programmatically. No need for a cart... I just want to skip it entirely. But it seems, as Loic has pointed out, there is no way around the cart object... so, is there a way I can fake this object data and just use the orders I have for the checkout, or do I need to go through the cart process?

Comment: You can skip cart page only if Cart object is not empty. So you have to make a fake free product, that is auto added to cart object… this is a good track... You can even hide it in checkout with some CSS or some JS… Then when you submit your order, It should be easy to remove it somewhere… For checkout fields you can manipulate them easily …

Comment: I can give you an idea. In WooCommerce -> Orders, you can manually add order. Then after creating the order, there's an option to send manually Customer invoice. In their email they will receive a link to where they can pay.

Comment: the link is also visible on the order you created. You can send it yourself in your preferred way. Link is like this `http://reigelgallarde.me/checkout/order-pay/1353/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_59657f64335ce`. I'm telling you this so will have an idea that it's possible. You can replicate this behavior in frontend too. But, as @LoicTheAztec mentioned, your question is too broad. I will not give a very long answer.

Comment: As Reigel is here now, you get with him some more real tracks…